# Log newly created files

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, logging

I would like to make a log of all newly created files and/or folders under a particular directory. I'm trying to monitor what files are being moved to and copied from a directory on OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.3

Answer (score 1):

`watch -d` highlights added and removed lines for 2 seconds:

```
watch -d ls
```

`-d=--cumulative` shows the highlights permanently:

```
watch -d=--cumulative ls
```

Or add a line like this to crontab:

```
* * * * * ls ~/Desktop/ > /tmp/desktop-$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S)
```

And then compare the files:

```
$ diff -y /tmp/desktop-20130604105700 /tmp/desktop-20130604105800
file1                               file1
                                  > file2
$ comm -13 /tmp/desktop-20130604105700 /tmp/desktop-20130604105800
file2
```